# Magento 2 codingStandardsIgnoreFile

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

In **phtml file** these comment used

`// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile`

e.g `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml` line **7**

Anyone know why it is used and can i use that too in my Extensions?

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can use that if you are using PHPCS (Code Sniffer) with the IDE.

PHPCS supports comment directives like:

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
```

You can get PHP_CodeSniffer to ignore specific files or lines in a file using comments.

Refer:
https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage

Comment: Below link will explain how to set PHPCS in PhpStorm:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Code+Sniffer+in+PhpStorm

And here is another url:
https://github.com/Islandora/islandora/wiki/Installing-and-configuring-codesniffer

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to continue the answer provided by [Oshan](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170537/146).

You can just use the same thing on your extensions. When you will run the code sniffer or the static tests on your extension, what is marked with `@codingStandardsIgnore*` will be ignored.
But you should try to avoid this as much as possible since using these annotations is just a way to hide the dirt under the rug.
**The fact that they are used in the core does not make it right to use them in your extensions.**

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that this is not advised. It's an attempt by Magento to hide issues they haven't had time to resolve yet - as a developer you should _not_ follow suit - fix the problem it's telling you about!